# Install package during pub get?

Tags: mongodb, flutter

During the installation fo mongo_dart 0.4.3 I received the following error (pub get)

```
Because every version of flutter_test from sdk depends on crypto 2.1.4 and mongo_dart >=0.4.1-dev.2.2 depends on crypto ^2.1.5, flutter_test from sdk is incompatible with mongo_dart >=0.4.1-dev.2.2.

So, because fluttermongo depends on both mongo_dart ^0.4.3 and flutter_test any from sdk, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because fluttermongo depends on both mongo_dart ^0.4.3 and flutter_test any from sdk, version solving failed.)
Process finished with exit code 1
```

my pubspec.yaml:

```
name: fluttermongo
description: A new Flutter application.


publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev


version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  mongo_dart: ^0.4.3
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
dependency_overrides:
  path: 1.6.4

flutter:

  uses-material-design: true
```

What am I missing ? how can I sove it ?

Comment: can you please provide your pubspec.ymal file?

Answer (score 0):

from

> flutter_test from sdk depends on crypto 2.1.4 and mongo_dart >=0.4.1-dev.2.2 depends on crypto ^2.1.5,

downgrade your fluttermongo version. check to see that it supports `crypto 2.1.4`